# How to read and separate non ascii character in a hive table column

Tags: hive, hiveql

How to separate the column value with comma,if column contains value like this format

`ổ,đĩa,á,mh,có`.

Output should be

`ổ đĩa á mh có`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use split function:

```
select splitted[0] as col1, 
       splitted[1] as col2,
       splitted[2] as col3,
       splitted[3] as col4,
       splitted[4] as col5
from
(
select split('ổ,đĩa,á,mh,có',',') as splitted
)s;
```

Returns:

```
OK
ổ       đĩa     á       mh      có
Time taken: 0.097 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

It seems your comma is different. It is not ascii 44 character. After copy-paste comma from your string, it works fine:

```
 select split('MÃƒÆ’Ã‚ÂºsicaÃƒÂ¯Ã‚Â¼Ã‚Å’Padre-HijoÃƒÂ¯Ã‚Â¼Ã‚Å’Fe','‚') ;
OK
["MÃƒÆ’Ã","ÂºsicaÃƒÂ¯Ã","Â¼Ã","Å’Padre-HijoÃƒÂ¯Ã","Â¼Ã","Å’Fe"]
```

Comment: When I am using split it starts showing as an array ["ổ,đĩa,á,mh,có"].but not removing comma.the datatype of column is string.do i need to change any basic property as well.

Comment: @Shivam In my demo it works, array is splitted. This ["ổ,đĩa,á,mh,có"] - is array of one element, right? It means split does not work. Show your code

Comment: Hi,the query is same as what you have suggested.If i am splitting data on any other delimiter e.g. "-" or "/" it is working fine,but i am not able to guess why this is not working for comma.I tried doing trim if any invisible whitespaces are there.but no luck.

Comment: @Shivam what client are you using: hive, hue, beeline?

Comment: This is beeline

Comment: select replace('MÃƒÆ’Ã‚ÂºsicaÃƒÂ¯Ã‚Â¼Ã‚Å’Padre-HijoÃƒÂ¯Ã‚Â¼Ã‚Å’Fe','-','/') ;   select replace('MÃƒÆ’Ã‚ÂºsicaÃƒÂ¯Ã‚Â¼Ã‚Å’Padre-HijoÃƒÂ¯Ã‚Â¼Ã‚Å’Fe',',','/') ;

Comment: did you see the different behavior both queries are showing?

Comment: @Shivam Yep. Now I see. Taken comma from your string  select ascii('‚');  And this is normal comma:  select ascii(','); Your comma returns -30, normal one is 44

Comment: @Shivam I copy-pasted comma from your string. and it works:hive> select regexp_replace('MÃƒÆ’Ã‚ÂºsicaÃƒÂ¯Ã‚Â¼Ã‚Å’Padre-HijoÃƒÂ¯Ã‚Â¼Ã‚Å’Fe','‚','/') ;
OK
MÃƒÆ’Ã/ÂºsicaÃƒÂ¯Ã/Â¼Ã/Å’Padre-HijoÃƒÂ¯Ã/Â¼Ã/Å’Fe   - replaced

Comment: @Shivam Split also works. Added example to the answer.

Comment: Yes,even i noticed the ASCII.Appreciate your valuable feedback and time.